# adding another value to 2d list

Tags: python

In Python I am writing a chi squared function to analyze pictures. Here is the current function which takes the RGB value for each pixel and places it into the list:

```
`def chiSquared(c):
    counter=0
    width, height = c.size
    matrix = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(height*width)]
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            matrix[counter][0]=c.getpixel((x,y))[0]
            matrix[counter][1]=c.getpixel((x,y))[1]
            matrix[counter][2]=c.getpixel((x,y))[2]
            counter+=1`
```

The matrix looks like:

```
[[230, 222, 218], [221, 218, 210], [218, 214, 206], [213, 206, 202], [214, 210, 206], [217, 215, 206], [218, 214, 210], [222, 218, 210], [225, 218, 214], [230, 222, 214], [221, 214, 206], [213, 211, 207], [205, 202, 198], [198, 194, 186], [177, 170, 166]...
```

what I would like to know: is there an easy way to add the values in each 3-tuple and create a 4-tuple where the last digit is the sum of the 3-tuple. IE for the matrix above -> [230,222,218] -> [230,222,218,670]

edit1: by easy I mean is there a better way then summing through the entire matrix (each 3-tuple) and creating a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
l=[[230, 222, 218], [221, 218, 210]]
[x+[sum(x)] for x in l]
Out[17]: [[230, 222, 218, 670], [221, 218, 210, 649]]
```

Comment: @user3831011 is this what you want ?